# ref object not found on event data after updating Firebase Cloud Functions into v1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After updating the firebase cloud functions into v1.0, the `ref` object which is suppose to be inside the realtime database triggers handler is missing.

Previously we used to get the `ref` object inside `event.data.ref`. After updating the Firebase Cloud Function into v1.0, they split the `event` handler into `data` and `context`. Now I can't find the `ref` object anywhere. It's not inside `data` or `context`. Calling `data.ref.parent` gives following error:

`Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined at module.exports.functions.database.ref.onWrite`

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the [migration guide for Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).

The first argument passed to an onWrite function is now a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object.  An RTDB `Change` object has a `before` and `after` property, each containing a DataSnapshot object with the contents of the database at the written location before and after the change.  These DataSnapshot objects have a `ref` property.

Comment: I am afraid it's not working. Inside my `.onWrite((change, context)`, getting `Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
    at change.after.ref.parent.child.once.then `.

Comment: Edit your question to include the complete, minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Actually adding the `ref` can be found under `after` and `before` property. Initially it was not there. After I deleted the function from https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=<project_id> and redeploying, it started working.